# How to store a counter start and stop number in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have created a counter which works great. What I am trying to do now is take the Number that is stored when the "Stop" button is pressed and it is added to the already existing value every time you start and stop the counter. 
I have used user defaults to store text field items in my app I'm just not sure how to store this counters value.

Here's my counter's code for reference if it helps.

```
// Start
@IBOutlet weak var startCoin: UIButton!
// Coins Label
@IBOutlet weak var countLabel: UILabel!
// Count Guts
var count:Int = 0
var counting:Bool = false
var timer:Timer = Timer()

// Start
@IBAction func startCoin(_ sender: Any) {
    if counting {
        // Stop Counting
        startCoin.setTitle("Start", for: .normal)
        timer.invalidate()
        counting = false
    } else if !counting {
        // Start Counting
        startCoin.setTitle("Stop", for: .normal)
        // Start timer
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector (counter), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        counting = true
    }
}

@objc func counter() -> Void {
    count += 1
    countLabel.text = "Coins: 0." + String(count)
}
```

Comment: do you want to store `var count:Int` ?

Comment: Yeah why is `count` not what you want?

Comment: Yeah i guess I didn't really word what  I want correctly. I want count to be stored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to store your `count:Int`, you might combine easily [`Computed Properties`](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html) and [`UserDefaults`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults), check this example:

```
var count:Int {
  get {
    return UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "count") ?? 0
  }
  set {
    UserDefaults.standard.set(newValue, forKey: "count")
    countLabel.text = "count: \(newValue)"
  }
}
```

Comment: So if that's how i store it, how would i get it to be displayed to a label of my choice?

Comment: Glad you found it useful. Feel free to up-vote and accept the answer :)

Comment: is there a way to store the counter number sort of like a highscore on another label?

Comment: it depends: if the "another label" is accessible during the highscore assignment (eg is in the same class), then you might do as explained above. If instead is in another class (eg.) then you have to refactor your code to be able to write inside that label.

Comment: Okay, how would I put this counter into it's own class?